# C++ overloading operator, constant parameter or pass by value?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, parameter-passing

```
template <typename T>
T operator+(T a, const T& b) {
    a += b;
    return a;
}

template <typename T>
T operator+(const T& a, const T& b) {
    T tmp {a};
    tmp += b;
    return tmp;
}
```

Is there any reason why you would pass argument as constant reference like the second function, over directly passing by value like the first function, since you need a temporary variable anyway?

---

Edit 1:

I think I should mention that these 2 functions alternative are just for handling case with lvalue arguments, and that I am to provide 2 other functions for handling with rvalue arguments, as follows.

```
template <typename T>
T operator+(T&& a, const T& b) {
    a += b;
    return std::move(a);
}

template <typename T>
T operator+(const T& a, T&& b) {
    b += a;
    return std::move(b);
}
```

So the emphasis of the question is, why would I need to explicitly create a temporary variable (function 2), when I can just let the language facilitate that automatically for me (function 1)?

Comment: Consider `a + b + c`. When you pass first argument by value, you can move from `a + b` temporary, when you pass by const-ref, you can't.

Comment: I personally prefer the first method.  That said, if performance is really critical, you should benchmark your use case to see which works best for you.

Answer (score 3):

```
template <typename T>
T operator+(T a, const T& b) {
    a += b;
    return a;
}
```

In here you are making a copy of variable **a** which is passed in here then you are updating a copy. which requires three copies to be created, and again you are returning by value.

```
template <typename T>
T operator+(const T& a, const T& b) {
    T tmp {a};
    tmp += b;
    return tmp;
}
```

in here your **tmp** variable has a local scope and variable **a** is const reference so no modification to the value of **a** is allowed.
And you are returning a copy of **temp** which is a local variable.

Both work fine but the difference is in the number of copies created. you are making more copies in 1 st case than of the second.

Although the second one will be optimized for **tmp** variable to use move semantics in order to make fewer copies. so you will have faster performance in 2nd case

Comment: compiler will optimize the copy returned to use move semantics

Comment: I *think* @Mouse alludes to the point that NRVO is not allowed in the first snippet as `a` is also a function parameter. The second snippet obviates that.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/M8f8os dummy example, the second will just do a copy, and the first a copy and move

Comment: @Bathsheba Good call.  I forgot function parameters don't qualify for RVO.

Comment: The first allows moving temporary results of subexpressions into the lhs parameter. The second will always copy there. That *could* be a pessimization compared to a superfluous move.

Comment: @Mouse _then you are updating a copy. which requires three copies to be created_, Why does it create 3 copies? I thought there is only 1 copy of `a` which is the only variable being modified and returned. _you are returning a copy of temp which is a local variable_ but in the first case, `a` is also a local variable in scope, which should qualifies for move operation, although not for NVRO.